# How to store color input values into a JavaScript dictionary?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, colors

Is trying to find a way to store input color values into a dictionary:

```
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorPicker">
```

But the current code can't make any input hex values store into the dictionary even with eventlistener added:

```
 var Colors = {
    "purple": "FF3CFF",
    "input": ""
 }    

 var colorInput = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
 colorInput.addEventListener("input", function(){
   Colors["input"] = colorInput.value.replace('#','');
 }, false);
```

The idea of the current code is to store the input color's hex values (removed hash symbol) to the `Colors` dictionary key `input` every time the input color changes. But now console.log shown no values can be add to "input"...

Update:
apparently the color values can only be recorded inside the addEventLister's function(), so are there anyways to make the values go outside it?

Comment: `But now console.log shown no values can be add to "input"...` where is that in your code?

Comment: Oh, simply add console.log(Colors) at the end of the js

Comment: To see the changes you should add that inside the event handler function.